# Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-file' - Ionic-cordova

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I was trying to install the plugin

> ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file

I'm getting error in cmd as

> Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-file': Error: ENOENT: no such file
>   or director y, open
>   'D:\product\project-1\frontend\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml'
>       at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
>       at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:551:33)
>       at Object.parseElementtreeSync (D:\product\project-1\frontend\platforms\andr
>   oid\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\util\xml-helpers.js:180:27)
>       at new AndroidManifest (D:\product\project-1\frontend\platforms\android\cord
>   ova\lib\AndroidManifest.js:29:20)
>       at AndroidProject.getPackageName (D:\product\project-1\frontend\platforms\an
>   droid\cordova\lib\AndroidProject.js:99:12)
>       at Api.addPlugin (D:\product\project-1\frontend\platforms\android\cordova\Ap
>   i.js:223:57)
>       at handleInstall (C:\Users\hi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_
>   modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\install.js:594:10)
>       at C:\Users\hi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova
>   -lib\src\plugman\install.js:357:28
>       at _fulfilled (C:\Users\hi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_mod
>   ules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\hi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\c
>   ordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
>
> (node:5240) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such
>   file or dir ectory, open
>   'D:\product\project-1\frontend\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xm l'
>       at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
>       at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:551:33)
>       at Object.parseElementtreeSync (D:\product\project-1\frontend\platforms\andr
>   oid\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\util\xml-helpers.js:180:27)
>       at new AndroidManifest (D:\product\project-1\frontend\platforms\android\cord
>   ova\lib\AndroidManifest.js:29:20)
>       at AndroidProject.getPackageName (D:\product\project-1\frontend\platforms\an
>   droid\cordova\lib\AndroidProject.js:99:12)
>       at Api.addPlugin (D:\product\project-1\frontend\platforms\android\cordova\Ap
>   i.js:223:57)
>       at handleInstall (C:\Users\hi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_
>   modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\install.js:594:10)
>       at C:\Users\hi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova
>   -lib\src\plugman\install.js:357:28
>       at _fulfilled (C:\Users\hi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_mod
>   ules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\hi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\c
>   ordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
>   (node:5240) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection  id: 1) (node:5240) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are depre cated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: What is the cordova version?
If 7.0.0, there is a breaking change affecting the AndroidManifest.xm file and breaking some plugins. Can you try version 6.4.0?

https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/12/04/cordova-android-7.0.0.html

Comment: My Cordova version is 8.0

Answer (score 0):

```
ionic cordova rm platform android
```

Then install the plugin. Then add the platform back.